# View complex Many to Many relationship on ADO.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net, many-to-many

I'm trying to update related database on many to many relationship using ADO.net

this is my database design[image]:

as you guys notice, entity framework wont mapping the class_student & subject_course, i've been searching the method and found this website: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

the website told me to make a viewModel, and i do so:

```
    namespace Test.Models.ViewModels
    {
        public class AssignedStudentData
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string course_code { get; set; }
            public bool Assigned { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

It's work flawlessly, but my problem is this line of code:

```
    private void PopulateAssignedStudentData(ms_class ms_class)
    { 
        var allStudent = db.ms_student; //this line is the problem
        var ClassStudent = new HashSet<int>(ms_class.ms_student.Select(c => c.ID));
        var viewModel = new List<AssignedStudentData>();
        foreach (var student in allStudent)
        {
            viewModel.Add(new AssignedStudentData
            {
                ID = student.ID,
                course_code = student.ms_course.course_name,
                Assigned = ClassStudent.Contains(student.ID)
            });
        }

        ViewBag.Students = viewModel;
    }
```

in var allStudent, i've tried to make so the system not generate all the student, but instead, student THAT ASSIGNED WITH A SUBJECT so for example:

```
    private void PopulateAssignedStudentDataBySubject(ms_class ms_class, int subject_id)
    { 
        //var allStudent = db.ms_student; //this line is the problem
        //My Version:

        var allStudentByCourse = db.ms_student.Include(m => m.ms_course).Where(m => m.ms_course.ms_subject.subject_id == subject_id); //this code is not working

        var ClassStudent = new HashSet<int>(ms_class.ms_student.Select(c => c.ID));
        var viewModel = new List<AssignedStudentData>();
        foreach (var student in allStudentByCourse )
        {
            viewModel.Add(new AssignedStudentData
            {
                ID = student.ID,
                course_code = student.ms_course.course_name,
                Assigned = ClassStudent.Contains(student.ID)
            });
        }

        ViewBag.Students = viewModel;
    }
```

i think the code won't work because the ms_course and ms_subject is a many-to-many relationship..

Thank you very much

**Class**

```
public partial class ms_course
{
    public ms_course()
    {
        this.ms_student = new HashSet<ms_student>();
        this.ms_subject = new HashSet<ms_subject>();
    }
    public int course_id { get; set; }
    public string course_code { get; set; }
    public string course_name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ms_student> ms_student { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ms_subject> ms_subject { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Where(m => m.ms_course.ms_subject.subject_id == subject_id)`, what is the type of ms_subject property ? Could you show the `ms_course` class?

Comment: I have moved the class definition from comment to the question, you should edit the question (there is an edit button under the tags) instead of put it in comment next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you're looking for students having a course that has at least one *specific* subject assigned to it. That would be:

```
db.ms_student
  .Where(s => s.ms_course.ms_subject
               .Any(sb => sb.subject_id == subject_id)))
```

It always helps me to articulate the problem clearly in terms of the object model first, as I did in the first sentence. It usually reveals what the query should look like.

Comment: Does `ms_course` look like a collection ? or just a reference ?

Comment: @YuliamChandra Thanks, I think you're right it's a reference. I changed it.

Comment: It's unclear anyway, OP should show the class definitions, but judging from the diagram `ms_student` has a `course_id`, that could mean one course has many students.

Answer (score 0):

What does the error message say?

You can try tis:

```
var allStudentByCourse = db.ms_student.Include(m => m.ms_course).Include("ms_course.ms_subject").Where(m => m.ms_course.ms_subject.subject_id == subject_id);
```

alternativ2 (this only works if ms_course has a fk property to ms_subject):

```
var allStudentByCourse = db.ms_student.Include(m => m.ms_course).Where(m => m.ms_course.subject_id == subject_id);
```

Update:

```
var allStudentByCourse = db.ms_student.Include(m => m.ms_course).Include("ms_course.ms_subject").Where(m => m.ms_course.ms_subject.Any(s => s.subject_id == subject_id));
```

Comment: the error said:
System bla bla, does not contain a definition for "subject_id" and no extension method "subject_id" accepting a first argument of type "system bla bla" could be found, (are you missing a using directive or an assemble reference?)

after the m.ms_course.ms_subject. the intellisense not generated the .subject_id or any other attribute on the table, but instead: Add, aggregate, all, etc

Comment: i've tried the first method, output still the same, i'm not using the alternative, because as you can see, my table design is a many-to-many relationship.. D:

Comment: Sorry, I didn't cach that ms_student was a list. I've added an update which I belive should work. I haven't tested it and I'm note sure EF appreciates a .Any() within the where() clause, but try it out.